# Should the contrast of the highlighted OP's name in comments be increased? Use this GM script if you want it changed now.

Tags: feature-request, comments, user-interface

Spot the OP!

**Old:**

---

[image]

---

**New:**

---

[image]

---

Here is a [link](https://stackapps.com/questions/2436/is-there-a-way-to-increase-the-contrast-of-the-special-highlighting-that-is-appli) to the Greasemonkey sript (works in Firefox, most probably also in Chrome). George made this for me. I cannot thank him enough: this is great! Note that you can easily change the colour of the highlighting by editing the `#ecd` thing in the code into something else. I have changed it into `#cdf` myself for a light-blue-greyish hue.